# Click vs Hold, Hold causing syntax error

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

Here is my XAML:

```
                    <Button x:Name = "Helloworld"
                        Content = "Hello world"
                        Grid.Column = "0"
                        Grid.Row = "0"
                        Click="playEvent"
                        Hold="setEvent"
                        Tag="/Sounds/helloworld.mp3" 
                    />
                    <Button x:Name = "Helloworld_ring"
                        Grid.Column = "1"
                        Grid.Row = "0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Click="setEvent"
                        Tag="/Sounds/helloworld.mp3">
                        <Image Source="/Images/note.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="30" Width="30" />
                    </Button>
```

And code behind like so:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        Button playSrcButton;
        Button setSrcButton;
        SaveRingtoneTask saveRingtoneChooser;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            saveRingtoneChooser = new SaveRingtoneTask();
            saveRingtoneChooser.Completed += new EventHandler<TaskEventArgs>(saveRingtoneChooser_Completed);
        }

        private void playEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            playSrcButton = e.OriginalSource as Button;
            playFile(playSrcButton.Tag.ToString(), playSrcButton.Content.ToString());
        }

        private void setEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            setSrcButton = e.OriginalSource as Button;
            saveRingtoneChooser.Source = new Uri(setSrcButton.Tag.ToString());
            saveRingtoneChooser.DisplayName = setSrcButton.Content.ToString();
            saveRingtoneChooser.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that if I put the setEvent function to happen on the click of the Helloworld_ring button then everything works fine.  If I try to eliminate these buttons and use the Hold event on the Helloworld function I get the error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyApp.dll
```

Which I understand is quite nondescript.  The problem I am noticing though is that during debugging the **setSrcButton** variable is not getting the value of **e.OriginalSource** but this *only* happens when I use the Hold event on Helloworld. When I use the Click event on Helloworld_ring then everything works fine.

All help is appreciated.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps e.OriginalSource is not your Button.

In this case sender should be your Button, so try that instead.

```
 setSrcButton = sender as Button;
```

Comment: While I wish someone would explain why this is the case, I very much appreciate the answer.  It works now. Thank you!